# User Input Validation (While Loop) Non-Number Entered where Number Requested (bash)

Tags: bash, validation, scripting, user-input, delimiter

I am trying to accomplish the task listed in the description below but am unsure of how I can validate a user's response when it comes to ensuring they do not input a letter, delimiter, or blank space as their user_number. Currently, when I run the script, it states "./loop_test.sh: line 12: [: a: integer expression expected". I have looked everywhere from Youtube, textbooks, and here but can't seem to figure out what is wrong...can someone help me out?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Description: This script will ask the user to enter a number between 20
# and 30. If the user enters an invalid number or a non-number, it will ask
# again. The process will repeat until a satisfactory number is entered.

# Option: None

printf "Hello! Select a number between 20-30: "
read user_number

while [ "$user_number" -lt 20 ] || [ "$user_number" -gt 30 ] && [ 
"$user_number" -ne *[0-9]* ]
do
    printf "Sorry, it looks like the input you selected isn't between 20-30\n"
    printf "Please select another number: "
    read user_number
done

printf "All set! Thanks for following directions!\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `bash`, you can use more advanced comparison, e.g. a pattern:

```
while [[ $user_number != +([0-9]) || ...
```

The first condition means *user input doesn't contain one or more digits*.

Comment: Hello, I have tried to make some of your edits to my code but I am still not understanding. I am hoping you may be able to better explain to me how to make it so that when the user is prompted for user_number and puts in a letter or decimal number, the system asks them to input another number.

Comment: The condition I showed just checks that $user_number is composed of digits exclusively. Add the range checks after it, i.e.

Comment: `while [[ $user_number != +([0-9]) ]] || (( user_number < 20 || user_number > 30 )) ; do read user_number; done`